# Error message Ajax, self updating field

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have made a script for a self updating field. Why do I get the following error message in this script:
UpdateField.html:37 Uncaught ReferenceError: fieldname is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange (UpdateField.html:37)

**Script:**

[image]

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<script>

function update_person(str,fieldname,key,keyvalue) 
{
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = 
xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","update_person.php?
q="+str+"&f="+fieldname+"&n="+key+"&nv="+keyvalue,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<form>
<input type="text" name="firstname" data-fieldname ="PERSONFORNAVN" data-key 
="PERSONID" data-keyvalue = "7" 
onchange = "update_person(this.value,this.data-fieldname, this.data-
key,this.data-keyvalue)">
</form>    
<br>
<div id="txtHint"> </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using custom data-attributes in html in onchange event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32460568/using-custom-data-attributes-in-html-in-onchange-event)

Answer (score 0):

> you need to remove space from the line 37 "? q=" is like "?q="

```js
function update_person(str,fieldname,key,keyvalue) 
{
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = 
this.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","update_person.php?q="+str+"&f="+fieldname+"&n="+key+"&nv="+keyvalue,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>



</head>

<body>

<form>
<input type="text" name="firstname" data-fieldname ="PERSONFORNAVN" data-key 
="PERSONID" data-keyvalue = "7" 
onchange = "update_person(this.value,this.data-fieldname, this.data-
key,this.data-keyvalue)">
</form>    
<br>
<div id="txtHint"> </div>
```